# Want to create Visual Studio Snippets but it gives error

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, lua, vscode-snippets

Want to create Visual Studio Snippets but it gives error.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNa9x.png)

Comment: You can't have two root elements.

Comment: And remove the `editor.tabcompletion` part, that is a setting and goes into your settings.json or just change it in your Settings gui.

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a JSON question than a Lua question.

Anyway, both of those entries need to be in the same object--remove the } at line 8 and the { at line 11. You can only have one root element in a .json file.